ProLiant DL380 Gen10 - Memory Configuration
We have a "ProLiant DL380 Gen10" with 2 x "Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5217 CPU @ 3.00GHz". Currently, each side of the CPU has 2 x 32GB RAM on "DIMM 8" and "DIMM 10", totalling 128GB.
We bought an additional 4 x 32GB RAM to double the memory to 256GB.
Where do we stick the additional RAM? Which DIMM do we use? The memories should be all the same.
Thanks,
Nelson

I think back side of the server chassis lid should have a quick pictorial guide about installing various hardware, including this one.

HPE publish the DIMM population rules. I think that this would be the document for gen10.
